# How to plot a table as png using gnuplot?

Tags: linux, shell, plot, gnuplot, tabular

I've crawled around the net, but could not find a sufficient solution for my issue. I have some csv-stuffed data of my cpu usage over time (per day split)

```
Time CPU used%
1    1   35
2    1   28
3    1   20
4    1   45
5    1   15
```

for each CPU that I have in my laptop. And on top of that I have some statistical calculated results of my usage from the last day like

```
CPU Max% Avg%
1   98  17
2   99  23
3   95  10
etc.
```

Using gnuplot I'm able to draw a line plot of my time series data and getting nice results. However I also want to add the statistics as a table beneath my line plot.

But I could not find a way to plot my raw data as a table using gnuplot. Does someone know a way? It doesn't have to be gnuplot, I just want to automate my plot-generation using shell commands, so gnuplot was very convenient for this.

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: You could add some of this as labels, but I would recommend using a proper document setting tool, e.g. HTML, Latex, etc.

Comment: Hi @Thor, do you have an example for Latex? I also though about this way in combination with gnuplot, but I wasn't sure how it works.

Comment: perhaps something like this - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146719

Comment: This looks like a [good example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121755/12347) as well. Note that this answer uses tikz for plotting the data, this may be a good idea as you are able to homogenize fonts etc.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Although this unanswered question is more than 3 years old, it still might be of interest to the OP or someone else.
It is not completely clear how your complete data looks like, i.e. whether is stored in a single file or in separate files.
So, I assumed something which is convenient to handle. It certainly can be adapted to other formats.

- The data will have a timestamp, the number of the CPU and the CPU usage value.
- Column separator is `tab`.
- The different CPUs are separated by two empty lines, with this you can address the different blocks via `index`.
- gnuplot can do the statistics via `stats`.
- For printing the statistics into the plot (as "table"), simply use labels (check `help label`).
- The example below is creating some random dummy data.
- The minimum CPU usage could also be easily added.

**Data:** (example one file, actually here: one datablock)

```
# date time             CPU     usage
2021-08-01 00:00:00     1       14.9574
2021-08-01 00:05:00     1       16.1165
2021-08-01 00:10:00     1       17.6627
2021-08-01 00:15:00     1       14.8799
...


2021-08-01 00:00:00     2       18.8313
2021-08-01 00:05:00     2       17.6595
2021-08-01 00:10:00     2       19.1912
2021-08-01 00:15:00     2       18.731
...


...
2021-08-01 00:00:00     8       39.9016
2021-08-01 00:05:00     8       37.8723
2021-08-01 00:10:00     8       40.2769
2021-08-01 00:15:00     8       38.9694
```

**Code:**

```
### plot time series and statistics label
reset session

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
t0 = strptime(myTimeFmt,"2021-08-01")
Ncpu = 8

# create some random test data
set print $Data
    p(t) = (_tmp=p0+rand(0)*6-3, _tmp>100 ? 100 : _tmp<0 ? 0 : _tmp)
    do for [cpu=1:Ncpu] {
        p0 = rand(0)*100
        do for [t=t0:t0+24*3600:5*60] {       # steps in 5 minutes for 1 day
            print sprintf("%s\t%d\t%g",strftime(myTimeFmt,t),cpu,p0=p(0))
        }
        print ""; print ""   # two empty lines
    }
set print

set datafile separator tab
set format x "%H:%M" time
set key out
set grid x,y
set xlabel sprintf("%s",strftime("Date: %Y-%m-%d",t0))
set ylabel "CPU usage / %" font ",12"

# create statistics:
set print $Statistics
    do for [i=1:Ncpu] {
        stats $Data u 3 index i-1 nooutput
        print sprintf("%d %.1f %.1f",i,STATS_max,STATS_mean)
    }
set print

set bmargin screen 0.25
myLabelPosY = 0.11

set label 1 at screen 0.02, screen myLabelPosY "\nMax:\nAvg:"
do for [i=1:Ncpu] {
    set label i+1 at screen 1./(Ncpu+1)*i, myLabelPosY \
       sprintf("CPU %d:\n%s%%\n%s%%",i,word($Statistics[i],2),word($Statistics[i],3)) 
}

plot for [i=1:Ncpu] $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):3 index i-1 w l ti sprintf("CPU %d",i)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I'm just seeing your awesome responses all over. I may have to just go to your profile and look for every question you responded to learn so much. I am disappointed that many of these answers have not been well appreciated.

Comment: @MathX thank you for your comment. Never mind, that's life. I am thrilled by finding solutions to interesting gnuplot questions with the given gnuplot options. And it is also a memory aid for myself. It happened that I had to look up old answers, because I forgot how to do it.

Comment: Also what Terminal do you usually use? your plots look very nice.

Comment: @MathX for most answers here, I am using the interactive terminal `wxt` under Windows and export the graph to PNG. The graphs created by terminal `pngcairo` usually look slightly different.

Comment: Yeah I am having issue with font png and pngcairo and none of the recommendations seem to work. I am actually doing what you're doing  (manually) and will potentially use a separate tool for conversion from emf, svg but it is annoying that it doesn't simply work.

Comment: @MathX if you have an issue with png output which is not covered or solved by previous questions, don't hesitate to open a new question.